# Crear multiples Dataframes de una carpeta con multiples archivos

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1.- Tengo una direccion que contiene 11 archivos, lo que deseo hacer en la funcion, es leer cada uno de los 11 archivos de la carpeta y crear un data frame distinto para cada uno de los archivos:

2.- Este es el código que tengo

```
def leer_ins(path):

    filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

    for i,filename in enumerate(filenames):
        nombre  = "0" + str(i) + filename
        nombre  = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 0)
            #list_data.append(data)

    return nombre

leer_ins("/Users/ricardo.javier.mart1/Documents/Sabadell/Insumos/Insumos_FinRep")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurre una posible solución definiendo una *Lista de DataFrames*. Esto sería una `lista` donde cada elemento es un `DataFrame`. Siguiendo tu planteo el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
def leer_ins(path):

    filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

    return [(pd.read_excel(i)) for i in filenames]    


#ej : 'C:/Users/MiPc/'
directorio = 'aca iría tu path'
resultado = leer_ins(directorio)
```

La función recibe la ubicación de la carpeta y devuelve la lista a través de una [comprensión de listas](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).

Si quieres acceder por ejemplo al primer `DataFrame` generado, en este caso deberías escribir `print(resultado[0])`. Al hacer `type(resultado[0])` el output es : `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. y al hacer `type(resultado)` el output es : `list`.

Comment: Excelente respuesta @Lucas Damian. Funciono perfectamente, unicamente añadi al final para recorrer toda la lista de DF un for con un enumerate. Así quedo al final:

Answer (score 0):

```
def leer_ins(path):

    filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
    return [(pd.read_excel(i)) for i in filenames]

#if lista in lista_in:

insumos_fr = leer_ins("/Users/ricardo.javier.mart1/Documents/Sabadell/Insumos/Insumos_FinRep")

for i, df in enumerate(insumos_fr):
    print(insumos_fr[i])
```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos agregar una descripción de lo que realiza el código, revisar [answer], saludos.